# How to create a lazy loading enabled one-to-one relationships with shared primary key way

Tags: java, hibernate, lazy-loading, one-to-one

I have a confusing problem on Hibernate assoication mapping, Here are the code snippet:

```
@Entity
public class Body {
    @Id
    public Long getId() { return id; }

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    public Heart getHeart() {
        return heart;
    }
    ...
}      

@Entity
public class Heart {
    @Id
    public Long getId() { ...}
}
```

As I got to know, if I want a lazy loading the heart entity while load a body, I have to add both fetch=FetchType.LAZY and optional=false to the annotation, it looks like:

```
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.LAZY, optional=false)
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
public Heart getHeart() {
    return heart;
}
```

The optional=false means that when a new body entity is persisted, the associated entity (here is heart) must also be set to body, such as body.setHeart(heart), but heart also need to set its member body: heart.setBody(), however, body is not yet persisted, so the value of the primary key column is null. if run the following code, exception will be thrown out.

```
Body body= new Body();
Heart heart = new Heart ();
heart.setBody(body);
body.setHeart(heart);
bodyDao.save(body);
```

the exception is:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: null id generated for:class org.fbb.domain.Heart
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:103)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:192)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:177)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:97)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:73)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSaveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:648)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:640)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CascadingActions$5.cascade(CascadingActions.java:218)
at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:398)
at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:323)
at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:162)
at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:111)
```

how to solve this issue? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Update your Heart entity as below

```
@Entity
Public class Heart{
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator=foreignmine)
@GenericGenerator(
       name="foreignmine",
       strategy="foreign",
       parameters=@Parameter(name="property",value="body"))
public Long getId(){return this.id}

private Body getBody(){return this.body}
```

This will tell hibernate to give primary key of Heart the value of the primary key of Body it is associated to

Comment: @ Zulfi  in your case,

Comment: @ylei .. didn't get you